# Angular Signal keeps returning empty array, from RxJs Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, signals

I keep getting an empty Array, when using Angulars toSignal function.

The observable returns an array of 5 objects.

But the signal returns an empty array.

Below is the Service code, and Component code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

ST

**API Service**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpringAPIService {

  private readonly baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';

  http = inject(HttpClient)

  getData(endpoint: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${endpoint}`;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const observable = this.http.get(url, { headers });
    return observable;
  }

}
```

**Angular 17 Component**

```
import { Component, Injector, Signal, inject, runInInjectionContext, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SpringAPIService } from '../spring-api.service';
import { toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrl: './projects.component.scss'
})
export class ProjectsComponent {

  http: SpringAPIService = inject(SpringAPIService);
  injector = inject(Injector);
  data: Signal<any> = signal([])

  ngOnInit() {
    runInInjectionContext(this.injector, () => {
      this.data = toSignal(this.http.getData('projects'), { initialValue: [] });
      console.log(this.data())
    });
 
  }

}
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/toSignal) "by subscribing to that Observable. The returned Signal will always have the most recent value emitted by the subscription"

Comment: my goal is to try and get a http request, and store it in a signal (rather than an observable). my http request works, but it returns an observable. But I'd like to work with a signal in the actual component. How is that done?

Comment: @Sachin your problem is that you are logging the signal value before the request has completed, so you are logging the `initialValue`. Try printing the value of the signal in the template and see if you get the results expected.

Comment: I think that was why. I've managed to get it working, when I read the signal elsewhere, e.g. in the template. Thanks!